# Twitter oauth2/token Tutorial always get error

Tags: twitter, token, oauth-2.0

I was follow the tutorial to make the request to obtain the response with token.But always get the error.

Here is the tutorial from...
https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth2/token

Here is the request from the postman I use.

```
POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.twitter.com
Authorization: Basic eHZ6MWV2RlM0d0VFUFRHRUZQSEJvZzpMOHFxOVBaeVJnNmllS0dFS2hab2xHQzB2SldMdzhpRUo4OERSZHlPZw==
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 7761e3d0-830e-eba4-00d7-9f964b3f3efb

grant_type=client_credentials
```

someone can help me? please.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: {
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 44,
      "message": "grant_type parameter is invalid",
      "label": "invalid_parameter"
    }
  ]
}